# NPE Crash in databinding when change the hierarchy of customView

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-databinding

```
import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.widget.FrameLayout

class MyCustomView @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet? = null)  : FrameLayout(
    context,
    attributeSet
) {
    val binding = MylayoutBinding.inflate(
        LayoutInflater.from(context),
        this,
        true
    )
}

// mylayout.xml
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <merge>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/myChildContainer"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"/>
    </merge>
</layout>
```

I am using my custom view in the form below.

```
// myactivity.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <MyCustomView
            android:id="@+id/myView"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/myButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </MyCustomView>
    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

In the example above, I want myButton to go into MyCustomView as a child of myChildContainer.

I followed the example from [android: how to add children from an xml layout into a custom view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258732/android-how-to-add-children-from-an-xml-layout-into-a-custom-view) and modified MyCustomView as below.

```
class MyCustomView @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet? = null)  : FrameLayout(
    context,
    attributeSet
) {
    val binding = MylayoutBinding.inflate(
        LayoutInflater.from(context),
        this,
        true
    )

    override fun onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate()
        while (childCount > 1) {
            val child = getChildAt(1)
            val param = child.layoutParams
            removeView(child)
            binding.myChildContainer.addView(child, param)
        }
    }
}
```

This code is fine if I don't apply data binding.

The problem is app has crashed when I apply data binding.

```
internal class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<MyactivityBinding>(this, R.layout.myactivity)
        binding.myButton.text = "Test Text" <-- crash
    }
}
```

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: binding.myButton must not be null
```

When I change the execution point of remove view and addview of my code from onFinishInflate to onAttachedToWindow, the error generally does not occur, but I have confirmed that it recurs intermittently, so I think this is not a solution.

Is there any way to add Child View to CustomView while keeping DataBinding?

I actually use multiple such views, so I don't want to call individual functions like myView.sortView() after setContentView.